# I am having a lot of trouble finding the right way to sort by price

Tags: sorting, collections, arraylist

I'm pretty sure that I have to use Collections, but I'm honestly super lost on how to implement it! My assignment needs me to

"Allow the user to view the plants sorted by price (lowest to highest), scientific name (alphabetized by genus), or common name (alphabetized by first letter of first word)."

this is my code, I don't know where to exactly put the sorting and how to write it in code :(

```
package plant.nursery.program;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PlantNurseryProgram {

private double maxHeightInFt;
private String commonName;
private String scientificName;
private double price;
boolean isFragile;

    public PlantNurseryProgram(String commonName, 
        String scientificName, double maxHeightInFt, double price, 
        boolean isFragile) {
        this.maxHeightInFt = maxHeightInFt;
        this.commonName = commonName;
        this.scientificName = scientificName;
        this.price = price;
        this.isFragile = isFragile;
    }


   @Override
   public String toString() {
        return commonName + " (" +  scientificName + ") " + "is " + 
            maxHeightInFt + " ft tall " + "it costs $" + price + " and "
            + "isFragile = " + isFragile;
   }

   public String setName(String newName){
       commonName = newName;
       return newName;
   }

   public String setSName(String newSName)
    {
        scientificName = newSName;
        return scientificName;
    }

   public double setHeight(double newHeight){
    maxHeightInFt = newHeight;
    return maxHeightInFt;
    }

   public double setPrice(double newPrice){
        price = newPrice;
        return price;
    }

   public boolean setFragile(boolean newFragile){
        isFragile = newFragile;
        return isFragile;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {        
    Scanner plant = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean toContinue = true;
    ArrayList<PlantNurseryProgram> plantNurseryAL = new ArrayList<>(); 

    do
    {
    System.out.println("What's the name of your plant");
    String commonName = plant.next();
    System.out.println("What's the scientific name for your plant?");
    String scientificName = plant.next();
    System.out.println("How tall is your plant?");
    double maxHeightInFt = plant.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("What's the price of your plant?");
    double price = plant.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Is the plant fragile? If yes type(true), if no "
            + "type (false)");
    boolean isFragile = plant.nextBoolean();
    System.out.println("Do you wish to continue?");
        toContinue = plant.nextBoolean();  

    PlantNurseryProgram userPlant = new PlantNurseryProgram( 
            commonName, scientificName, maxHeightInFt, price, isFragile);

    plantNurseryAL.add(userPlant);

    System.out.println("Is all the information you entered correct?");
    boolean corrections = plant.nextBoolean();
    if(corrections == false)
    {
        System.out.println("What would you like to correct?"
                 + " 1. Name, 2. Scientific name, 3. Height, 4. Price"
                + "5. Fragility?" );
        int userChoice = plant.nextInt();
        if(userChoice == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter the correct name");
            String newName = plant.next(); 
            userPlant.setName(newName);
            System.out.println(userPlant);
        }
        else if(userChoice == 2)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter the correct scientific name");
            String newSName = plant.next();
            userPlant.setSName(newSName);
            System.out.println(userPlant);
        }
        else if(userChoice == 3)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter the correct height");
            double newHeight = plant.nextDouble();
            userPlant.setHeight(newHeight);
            System.out.println(userPlant);
        }
        else if(userChoice == 4)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter the correct price");
            double newPrice = plant.nextDouble();
            userPlant.setPrice(newPrice);
            System.out.println(userPlant);
        }
        else if(userChoice == 5)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter if the plant is fragile or not");
            boolean newFragile = plant.nextBoolean();
            userPlant.setFragile(newFragile);
            System.out.println(userPlant);
        }    
    }   
 } while(toContinue == true);

    for (PlantNurseryProgram plantNurseryProgram : plantNurseryAL) {
            System.out.println(plantNurseryProgram);
    } // end of for loop
} //end of main
} // end of class
```

Answer (score 1):

You're posting too much here.  To figure out what to do, you don't need a `main` method or a user interface. By the way, conventionally, setters are `void` methods.

You should become familiar with the available methods for collections in the `java.util` package.  Or you can use the index and look up `sort`. You will see that the `Collections` class has two `sort` methods.  One is for the case when the class is inherently `Comparable`:

```
public class TemperatureGauge implements Comparable<TemperatureGauge> {...}
```

The other is when a class may be sorted many different ways, so that there is no natural way to define a standard comparison.  Then, you create a `Comparator`.

```
public class CommonNameComparator implements Comparator<PlantNurseryProgram> {
    public int compare(PlantNurseryProgram left, PlantNurseryProgram right) {
        // Do something with left.getCommonName() and right.getCommonName().
        // It must return a negative, zero, or positive depending on whether
        // left should come before, in the same place, or after right.
        return /*anInteger*/;
    }
}
```

Repeat the process for the scientific name and the price.

For extra credit, write JUnit tests for each comparator and for the sorting process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use set interface of collection class.Before that first you should override the equals and hashcode method in your code with the field according to which you want to short.
After this you can create object of PlantNurseryProgram and this in one of the subclass of set interface.As per your requirement you can use Treeset class.
Reemember there are several other ways to ddo this.Using set you can not duplicate item.

If your purpose is to sort after inserting the data in data structure the use sort method provided in java collection api.

See the below link.

http://www.roseindia.net/java/jdk6/set-interface.shtml